# Why do I keep being asked to upgrade by GDB to LLDB?

Tags: debugging, xcode4.3, lldb

[image]

Yes I click perform changes. I thought obviously finally it'll work right.

That issue show up as warning again and again and again. I AGREED to it. So it should have been changed and all problem should be fixed right? 2 or 3 next compile again, I saw the same warning again and get asked the same thing again.

Comment: I had a similar problem that eventually turned out to be my Version Control System.   Somehow either the changes were not being made or they were not being noticed and the VCS was overwriting the changes.   If you are using one, you might want to check that the changes were made to the scheme right after agreeing to it,

Comment: I do not know what version control system is. How do we check that changes were made to the scheme

Comment: The best way to check that the changes were made would be to diff the old xcscheme (from before the change) files vs. the new ones.   This is done quickly and easily with a Version Control System (git, Perforce, mercurial, CVS, RCS, etc.)  or by copying off the old one and doffing the directory.

Comment: Xscheme is the extension for the file type that is used to store the schemes, which is where these changes are made.   They are stored in a sub-directory of the project folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem in Xcode 4.3.3. I fixed this by manually editing the appropriate file, using a text editor.

1. Close Xcode.
2. Use Finder to open MyProject.xcodeproj (right-click and select "Show Package Contents").
3. Navigate in Finder down to xcuserdata/[username].xcuserdatad/xcschemes
4. Open MyProject.app.xcscheme in a text editor (right-click and select "Open With")
5. Find the line(s) that read:

   ```
   selectedDebuggerIdentifier = "Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.Debugger.GDB"
   ```

and change to

```
    selectedDebuggerIdentifier = "Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.Debugger.LLDB"
```

Save, close, open XCode. The message should now be gone.

Answer (score 0):

When you make the switch from xcode 4.2 to 4.3 this comes allong with LLVM set of tools.I am not sure what is happening in your case but you can suppress these warnings using the following steps..

product->edit scheme: GDB in the debug scheme for the debugger.

Comment: I want LLVM. The issue is it's not handled properly.